# Why solr is not giving any results for a term after adding synonyms for that term in synonyms_query.txt?

Tags: solr, solr6

> I am using ***apache-solr6.6.0*** as a search engine for my project.I was about to add some synonyms for some terms in solr.For example- I had to add ***tshirts,polo shirts,jersey*** as synonyms.I added them in synonyms_query.txt during query time.But after adding them,when I searched for tshirts, it displayed zero results although searching tshirt gave results.When I changed it to ***tshirt,polo shirts, jersey***; it displayed zero results for tshirt but showed results for tshirts?Below is the **managed schema** file extarct for search field:

```
   <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" 
   ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
  synonyms="synonyms_index.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" 
  generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" 
  catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
  <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" 
  protected="protwords.txt"/>
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" 
   ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
   synonyms="synonyms_query.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" 
  generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" 
  catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" 
  protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

Below are the screen shots from my ***Analysis*** Section:
 [image: Analysis Image Part1]
 [image: Analysis Image Part2]

Comment: Use the "Analysis" screen under the Admin page for your collection to get a step by step display of how your content and query is processed - it'll tell you exactly where the mismatch happens and why the content on both sides doesn't match.

Comment: @MatsLindh I have added the relevant screenshots.I have added tshirt,polo shirts,jersey in my synonyms_query.txt file.

Comment: What you have on the index side is also important (i.e. what the content of the field has been indexed as), since it's impossible to try to say why you're not getting a match without knowing what you're matching against.

Comment: @MatsLindh I am unable to add it in the question itself.So, I am sending here.These are the screenshots for index analysis https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeYcZ.png 
  ,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kVEy.png

Comment: @MatsLindh If results are not there for a particular synonym, is it possible that zero results are shown for each and every synonym ? I have the following as synonym : Tunic, shirt dresses, longline top, highlow top, mockhem, Maxi tops,kurta.When I search for kurta , no results are shown with this synonym config. When I remove the synonyms, results are shown for kurta and since mockhem is not there no results are shown.Can I conclude that since mockhem is not present, no results are shown for the synonyms.Does Solr ands all the synonyms?